# Page not found error in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am new to Laravel. I have installed Laravel and also integrated it. But when I wrote the following code in routes.php I am getting page not found error.

```
Route::get('/hello',function(){
   return 'Hello World!';
 });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its asking for a page

Comment: As per documentation I guess return 'Hello World'; will write hello world on the page.